# IntelliJ doesn't allow newlines with Vue.js component templates

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, vue.js, webstorm

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Vue.js, and I'm having a slight issue when it comes to defining component templates. Simply put, IntelliJ won't let them be longer than one line without trying to concatenate then

Example

```
Vue.component('app-button', {
    template: '<div class="button-container"><div class="button-outer"><div class="button-inner"></div></div></div>'
});
```

And when I try to space it out so one HTML tag is on each line..

```
Vue.component('app-button', {
    template: '<div class="button-container">' +
    '<div class="button-outer">' +
    '<div class="button-inner">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

This make it difficult to define templates to say the least. Is there a way to make IntelliJ work better with these strings? If not, can I define them in a separate file or something?

Comment: That's definitely correct JavaScript syntax. I would recommend being more modular and creating external files.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ES6 templates (http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation), like this:

```
Vue.component('app-button', {
    template: `<div class="button-container"><div class="button-outer"><div class="button-inner"></div></div></div>`
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I needed to use back ticks, I thought those were just apostrophes! It works as expected in IntelliJ with back ticks, my HTML is much easier to read now. Thank you.